# How to split field with dynamic delimiter

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with contact emails.

```
name_family@company.com

name-family@company.com

name.family@company.com
```

I need to extract name and family to separate columns.
I wrote this SQL code but looking for other/better ways to do this

```
WITH emailWithUnserscore AS
      (SELECT *,
              SPLIT(SPLIT(string_field_0, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)],'_')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS firstName,
              SPLIT(SPLIT(string_field_0, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)],'_')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS lasttName
       FROM `project.dataset.contacts`
       WHERE LENGTH(SPLIT(SPLIT(string_field_0, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)],'_')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]) > 0 ),
         emailWithMinus AS
      (SELECT *,
              SPLIT(SPLIT(string_field_0, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)],'-')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS firstName,
              SPLIT(SPLIT(string_field_0, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)],'-')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS lasttName
       FROM `project.dataset.contacts`
       WHERE LENGTH(SPLIT(SPLIT(string_field_0, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)],'-')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]) > 0 ),
         emailWithDot AS
      (SELECT *,
              SPLIT(SPLIT(string_field_0, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)],'.')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS firstName,
              SPLIT(SPLIT(string_field_0, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)],'.')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS lasttName
       FROM `project.dataset.contacts`
       WHERE LENGTH(SPLIT(SPLIT(string_field_0, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)],'.')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]) > 0 ),
         allEmails AS
      (SELECT *,
              SPLIT(string_field_0, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS firstName,
              '' AS lasttName
       FROM `project.dataset.contacts`)
    SELECT allEmails.string_field_0 AS Email,
           if(LENGTH(emailWithUnserscore.lasttName) > 0, emailWithUnserscore.firstName, if(LENGTH(emailWithMinus.lasttName) > 0, emailWithMinus.firstName, if(LENGTH(emailWithDot.lasttName) > 0, emailWithDot.firstName, allEmails.firstName))) AS firstName,
           if(LENGTH(emailWithUnserscore.lasttName) > 0, emailWithUnserscore.lasttName, if(LENGTH(emailWithMinus.lasttName) > 0, emailWithMinus.lasttName, if(LENGTH(emailWithDot.lasttName) > 0, emailWithDot.lasttName, allEmails.lasttName))) AS lastName
    FROM allEmails
    LEFT JOIN emailWithUnserscore ON allEmails.string_field_0 = emailWithUnserscore.string_field_0
    LEFT JOIN emailWithMinus ON allEmails.string_field_0 = emailWithMinus.string_field_0
    LEFT JOIN emailWithDot ON allEmails.string_field_0 = emailWithDot.string_field_0
    ORDER BY Email DES
```

Comment: It's unclear but seems like you are trying to extract names from email addresses? Just wondering what you expect when you get no separator or more than expected eg bob741@email.com, first.middle.last@blah.com, bob.double-barrelled@...

Comment: Yes, I need to extract name and family to separate columns and your point is very good. I was looking to get a good stable starting point SQL and build on top of this other use cases

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.contacts` AS (
  SELECT 'name_family@company.com' email UNION ALL
  SELECT 'name-family@company.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'name.family@company.com' 
)
SELECT 
  email,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(email, r'(.*?)[_\-.]') firstName,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(email, r'[_\-.](.*?)@') lastName
FROM `project.dataset.contacts`
```

result

```
Row     email                       firstName   lastName     
1       name_family@company.com     name        family   
2       name-family@company.com     name        family   
3       name.family@company.com     name        family
```

Comment: glad it worked for you. please consider also voting up :o)